# How can I read all documents in Firestore except one or more?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Can I read all documents in Firestore except one or more ?

*For example :*

```
5unvCwc3EjU4wlvyhcFd //- This is document id
70NnxwyChAnjfkYZTyO0 //- This is document id
QJAjwfMWiv9OrUKYnG40 //- This is document id
1mgDgDWPrMuI4di8HnvQ //- This is document id
siv9DfYUkPUVhAG4NRWj //- This is document id

//I want read all documents except 1mgDgDWPrMuI4di8HnvQ and 70NnxwyChAnjfkYZTyO0
```

I need to do that because my app has approximate ten thousands users and Firestore gives us 50,000 reads daily and I think It's not enough for me so I want avoid unnecessary reads.

I'll be glad to correct english language because It's not my language and thanks advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no operation to exclude a specific document or range of documents from the results you get from Firebase in a single operation.

What you can do is use a range query to **include** only a specific range. You could potentially execute multiple range queries to then create the results you need. But I doubt the extra code and overhead it worth the number of documents you don't want to read.

If you're reading 50K documents with a low number of users, you should typically consider denormalizing/restructuring your data to require fewer reads per user. For example, if you're showing the latest news headlines on your main page/activity when the user starts the app, do you really need to read 10-20 individual news documents? Or could you combine the 10-20 headlines into a single document, and read only that document.

For more of these types of tips, I highly recommend watching the video series [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: I save posts in room database , When user run application the app must goes check in Firestore if there new posts by users or no but without read same data in room database.

Comment: The most common approach I take for that is to have a `last_updated_at` timestamp field/property in the data, and then query for that.

Comment: I have simple question :
I have this document `70NnxwyChAnjfkYZTyO0` and this document has array , Furthermore this array has 318 item.
*The main question is if I read this array so will be 1 of 50,000 or 318 of 50,000* in reads count ?

Comment: You're charged for **document** reads that happens on the server. If you're reading one document, you'll be charged for one document read.

Comment: Thank you so much.